# ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, six

Currently I am using Django version 3.0.7
Earlier i was working on 3.0.5 and getting error of : Trying to load rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework 
Error: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
Then i changed it to "from django.urls import reverse" this error got fixed but below written error generated, so i upgraded Django version to 3.0.7 but still there is same error.

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\QuickChat\project>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 120, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templatetags\rest_framework.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.utils import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 76, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 24, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 42, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 107, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 122, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils' (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Where you have installed Django? Do you use virtualenv? Have you activated it?

Comment: When you upgrade Django, you need to upgrade related packages as well. In this case, the error *when trying to load 'rest_framework...'* is telling you that you need to upgrade Django Rest Framework.

Comment: *Then I changed it to "from django.urls import reverse"* - it's not a good idea to modify the code of apps you installed using `pip`. First, try to find a version of the app that works with your project and install that.